# SMTP error even after unlocking captcha and allowing less secure apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, smtp, gmail, smtp-auth

I'm have a rails app with a simple contact form that forwards messages to my gmail.I have successfully gotten the form working in the past, although every once in a while I'll have to unlock captcha (here - https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) to re-grant my site access to my gmail.

This time, though, the site cannot send emails, even after unlocking captcha (as well as enabling less secure apps to access my gmail - details [here][https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255]. (but works locally..)

*heroku error log*

```
2017-08-12T14:58:28.899110+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 480ms
2017-08-12T14:58:28.900185+00:00 app[web.1]: Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbvN
2017-08-12T14:58:28.900186+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2017-08-12T14:58:28.900187+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:12:in `create'
```

Comment: Hi I have same issue, have you got solution?